# why is my listview empty after goback?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, win-universal-app

I have a listview with itemsource="{Binding}" in the MainPage.
and with this code i fill it.

```
        viewContacts.ItemsSource = null;
        viewContacts.ItemsSource = itemsList;
```

itemsList is a ObservableCollection and that works.

I also have a functon if i press on a item to Navigate to another page.

```
        private void viewContacts_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var clickedcontact = e.ClickedItem as contact;
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(contactdetails), clickedcontact);
    }
```

contactdetails is a DetailPage.

if I go back with this code to the DetailPage.

```
        private void App_BackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Frame.CanGoBack)
        {
            Frame.GoBack();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

My list is empty and I have to press search another one to find contacts.

Back at WP8.1 my list wasn't empty and got filled with the results from before.

Windows Universal App 10, VS 2015, C#, XAML

Answer (score 2):

first if you do `viewContacts.ItemsSource = itemsList;`there is no need to do  `itemsource="{Binding}`. 
Second, do you do any LoadState or SaveState when you leave the page or do you save your data at OnNavigatedFrom or load them OnNavigatedTo??

For you data to continue to exist you must save them somewhere.
The easiest and fastest way is to keep them in static like:

```
public static ObservableCollection<MyClass> itemsList = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
```

Comment: ad1: actually i hate that Binding thing, i dont understand it...
I don't do any Load and Save State.. i got a json list with contacts and they are in my Listview, i dont have any other data ^^
ad2: Nice, the static was missing :)

Comment: Bindings are powerful and i love them. Its really easy to understand how binding works for example if you create a public ObservableCollection<MyClass> ItemsList {get; set;} in your code and  in xaml you add itemsource="{Binding ItemsList}"  done boom your list is loaded.

Comment: No need for any other code, and if you change something in your list it automatically updates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the NavigationCache to required so it keeps the input.
Take a look at this msdn page:
[Page.NavigationCacheMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.navigationcachemode%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

So the page doesn't need to reload all the stuff.